# Why all my works are deleted?

Tags: 20.04, updates, ros

I use ubuntu 20.04 recently on my laptop windows 10. ubuntu recommended me to install ubuntu 20.04.4 and without it I couldn’t install ROS. So I install it and Ros has been downloaded successfully. But the problem is that after I finished all that I powered off the operating system and the next day I opened the system and everything came back. Even the recommendation of installing ubuntu 20.04.4. And Ros doesn’t exist anywhere. That was so frustrating. Please help me!

Comment: Are you sure you haven't booted the installation media?  An install Ubuntu system doesn't include the installer (*that's usually only found on installation media but doesn't itself get installed; though it's possible to install the installer onto an existing installed system*) thus won't offer to install anything; thus it sounds like you've booted a *live* system that will appear '*new*'.

Comment: more specifically: did you pull out the USB you used to install Ubuntu once you were done? if you didn't, then shut down the laptop, pull out the drive, and turn it on again.